# Installation, dual operating systems

Tags: dual-boot, usb, system-installation

I'm about to switch my OS from Windows XP to Ubuntu on an HP laptop, primarily for internet use.
Is there an "idiot's guide" anywhere here that I can print up before I try it?
The plan is to put the OS on a separate USB hard drive so, if I really mess up, I won't lose everything on the laptop HD. 
I have some technical programs on the laptop that won't run on anything but Windows so I will still need XP on occasion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I remember following [this guide](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installing) from Psychocats when I first started out on Ubuntu nervously. It covers everything you need with helpful screenshots. There appears to be an updated guide [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/installing-ubuntu/).

As usual, the normal caveats apply. Backup your data before attempting any OS installation.

Answer (score 0):

simple method

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

complex method

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a backup of your most important data.  However, in all my years (since 1992) I have never lost any data while installing Linux.  I don't know how, but some people have. Some people loose their data even without trying to install a new OS.

As far as an 'idiot's" guide, there's the installation procedure which is simply to burn the iso and boot to it.  I can't imagine it being simpler than just following the default prompts to install along side windows.

When the install finishes it'll boot with an option to choose between Ubuntu or Windows for booting.

Windows should be easy because you are familiar with it.  Ubuntu is easy because it just is.

The OS has a Launch bar with a Firefox Icon of which clicking it, and Firefox works no different than the way it works in Windows.

By the way, if you were able to find someone who had never used a computer and gave them two systems to use, Ubuntu would most likely be the easiest to use.

Some of my friends who are not familiar with Linux by knows the Mac, thank they are looking at a Mac computer when they see my environment.

As far as guide, click on the launch button (the button on top of the Launch bar) and type "help".  You'll find a guide there to help you navigate the already very easy to use environment.